# MDL Tables Selectable not working as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, datatables, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm using Material Design Lite and trying to implement a basic data table with the code below:

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>$2.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>$1.25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>$2.35</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The table generates fine, but the above code does not generate the checkboxes that I need.  Based on the documentation mdl-data-table--selectable should generate the checkboxes, but they are not showing up.  I did some digging around and found this article on github: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations.

While this is a bit disappointing, I copied their example just to see if it generates the checkboxes correctly.  My exact code is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>


    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
          <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select" for="table-header">
            <input type="checkbox" id="table-header" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          </label>
      </th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select" for="row[1]">
            <md-checkbox type="checkbox" id="row[1]" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          </label>
      </td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>$2.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select" for="row[2]">
            <input type="checkbox" id="row[2]" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          </label>
      </td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>$1.25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select" for="row[3]">
            <input type="checkbox" id="row[3]" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
          </label>
      </td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>$2.35</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I've included all the necessary links to the JS and CSS file, but what returns looks like this:

[image]

For consistency, I really need the checkboxes to have the Material Design look/feel, but this looks like Bootstrap.  Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>
```

Try something like this? Some reference material: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section/checkbox

Or perhaps it has to with the fact that you an outdated version of MDL? The current version is 1.3.0